# Maven2 Installation: Missing artifact

Tags: eclipse, maven

I need Maven for an imported project. I installed it with „Install new software“.
And the error 'missing artifact' appeared.
So, I downloaded the 12.2.0.1-Jar and added it to referenced libraries with add external Jar. Then Maven -> Update Project -> check forced doesent work either.
What am I doing wrong?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14LIk.png)

[dic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtzcM.png)

[dic_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYKkJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `.lastUpdated` files mean that Maven tried to download the files but failed. It caches this information in these `.lastUpdated` files.

The "add external jar" functionality is probably just an Eclipse functionality and does not really add anything for Maven. For Maven, you need to install the file into the local repository with `install:install-file`.

Comment: I installed Maven in Windows, then the plugin, then Maven Update Forced and it works.
Thank you